# Error with IF/OR in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
.Range("BS2:BS" & NewLastRow).Formula = "=IF((OR(BR2=""FLAG"",BO2>0)),""FLAG"",""NOFLAG"" ))"
```

I am using this formula in VBA but it is not working. Syntax looks fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many ")"

```
.Range("BS2:BS" & NewLastRow).Formula = "=IF(OR(BR2=""FLAG"",BO2>0),""FLAG"",""NOFLAG"" )"
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, try the following:

- Make a workable formula in Excel
- Then select the cell with the workable formula
- Run the following code

---

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()

    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula

End Sub
```

---

- In the immediate window something useful should be printed.

Source:
[Apply formula in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45463062/apply-formula-in-vba/45463372#45463372)