# Apply formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply a formula that writes YES or NO in a cell checking if another cell starts with Q) text.

Writing it manually in Excel is working.

```
=IF(LEFT(A2;2)="Q)";"YES";"NO")
```

But when I try to do it automatically inside a macro

```
Range("R2").Formula = "=IF(LEFT(A2;2)=""Q)"";""YES"";""NO"")"
```

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Also, I will want to do it for the whole column, something like this

```
Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(A2;2)=""Q)"";""YES"";""NO"")"
```

But for that I have to solve the first problem before.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: LEFT(A2,2) - use a comma, not a semicolon

Comment: Those semicolons (;) should be commas (,)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBA uses the comma separator, irrespective of your local settings

```
Range("R2:R" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(LEFT(A2,2)=""Q)"",""YES"",""NO"")"
```

Comment: This solved the problem, I will accept is as soon as possible. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try the record macro option:
 1. Start recording
 2. Paste the formula into a cell
 3. Stop recording
 4. Look at the recorded macro and how it formats the formula

Comment: I tried that but it used R1C1 format and I am not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

In general, try the following:

- Make a workable formula in Excel
- Then select the cell with the workable formula
- Run **the code**
- In the immediate window something useful should be printed.

---

**The code**:

```
Public Sub PrintMeUsefulFormula()
    Dim strFormula  As String
    Dim strParenth  As String

    strParenth = """"

    strFormula = Selection.Formula
    strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

    strFormula = strParenth & strFormula & strParenth
    Debug.Print strFormula
End Sub
```

Source: [Error with IF/OR in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441679/error-with-if-or-in-vba/45441770#45441770)

Answer (score 1):

The `Range.Formula` is expecting a EN-US syntax.

Use `Range.FormulaLocal` to insert a formula based on your regional settings:

```
Range("R2").FormulaLocal = "=IF(LEFT(A2;2)=""Q)"";""YES"";""NO"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double double-quotes. try skipping the double quotes with .

For example: instead of ""Q"" try \"Q\"

Comment: This is not vb.Net, this is `VBA`. Escape symbols are different.