# How to convert a basic excel function to be used in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to use VLOOKUP within VBA to provide a value in a newly inserted row when the code is run. I am using the method of "" to type VLOOKUP in the search bar rather than using worksheet function. However, I am struggling to type the correct formula. The cell number is unknown hence why im using a variable.

delivActivEnd is just a variable that has been defined to find the needed cell number. Does any one know how to correctly write this for VBA?

```
ws.Range("G" + CStr(invoicingStart + delivPos)) = "=VLOOKUP(=$C" + (CStr((delivActivEnd)) + "'Sub tasks'!B:T,16,False")
```

Comment: The formula property of the range would help and remove one of the `=` - `ws.Range("G" + CStr(invoicingStart + delivPos)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP($C" + (CStr((delivActivEnd)) + "'Sub tasks'!B:T,16,False")`

Comment: Unfortunately still get application defined or object defined error

Comment: Replace the `+` and with `&` in the formula, the latter is used for concatenation of strings in VBA.

Comment: Still produces an error

Comment: Have you tried to come up with a solution from the duplicate?

Comment: Too many brackets? yes ive checked the brackets

Comment: This one - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45441770/5448626

Comment: What is meant to go here? "strFormula = Replace(strFormula, """", """""")

Comment: obviously a replace of `""""` with `""""""`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `.Formula` is the property of a formula;
- `=` should be once only and it should be **before** the formula;
- `&` is the operand for concatenation in VBA;

Try this:

```
Sub Testme()

    Dim delivActivEnd As Long
    delivActivEnd = 42
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C" & delivActivEnd & ",'Sub tasks'!B:T,16,False)"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much worked perfectly! If i was to do an IF function, and if the test was True want it to display "OK" how would i do that as it thinks the "" are the end of the statement

Comment: @Lawrence Forster - give it a few tries, put a bit "" and see what is happening.